# How to position a button using grid row and column definitions?

Tags: xaml, button, grid, position, windows-phone-8.1

I've set up a `Windows Phone 8.1` project and right now I'm trying to place a button, in the centered horizontally near the bottom of the layout.

So far I've figured out the following to center the button on the layout, but the 
`Grid.Row` setting doesn't seem to have any effect on the vertical positioning as I expected.

Does anyone know how I can position the button towards the bottom of the screen? At the moment its in the center but half way up the screen, needs to be towards the bottom of the screen.

```
<Page x:Class="LC_Points.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:LC_Points"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},
                            Path=MainViewModel}"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="2"
                Content="Calculate"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you set *Grid.Row* property of an element, first you have to define the rows of the Grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click Me!" />
</Grid>
```

If you change the *Height* properties of the *RowDefinitions*, you can easily position the *Button* vertically.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="90*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click Me!" />
</Grid>
```

10* means 10% of the Grid. Sum of the stars has to be equal 100.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I define the horizontal positioning using the grid? At the moment the button is left justified, need it to be centered horizontally.

Comment: Similarly, you should define the columns. Split the grid three equal columns(without width attributes) and set the grid.column property of button to 1.

Comment: Okay I tried this. http://hastebin.com/uyidilimog.xml but the button is now bottom right. Can you show a code example of what you mean?